# OrderState creation and deletion

Tags: php, module, prestashop, payment, prestashop-1.5

I'm developing a payment module for Prestashop 1.5. As there is no order state related to the payment, I decided to create one during the install process.

I used [this](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/21883-solved-add-order-state-problem/) topic from the official forum, which suggests to use this

```
$OrderState = new OrderState();
            $OrderState->name = array_fill(0,10,"Saman Bank Payment accepted");
            $OrderState->template = array_fill(0,10,"SB24");
            $OrderState->send_email = 1;
            $OrderState->invoice = 1;
            $OrderState->color = "#f8dbec";
            $OrderState->unremovable = false;
            $OrderState->logable = 0;
            $OrderState->add();
```

So now the createOrderState looks like this

```
private function createOrderState($db_name, $name)
{
    if (!Configuration::get($db_name))//if status does not exist
    {
        $orderState = new OrderState();
        $orderState->name =  array_fill(0,10,$name);
        $orderState->send_email = false;
        $orderState->color = 'royalblue';
        $orderState->hidden = false;
        $orderState->delivery = false;
        $orderState->logable = false;
        $orderState->invoice = false;
        if ($orderState->add())//save new order status
        {
            Configuration::updateValue($db_name, (int)$orderState->id);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I install the module and go to check in the Order States list I find inserted four empty statuses (ids 14,15,16 and 17) and the one I intended to create (id 18).

On the other hand, the uninstall function contains the deleteOrderState function, which is like this

```
public function deleteOrderState($db_name, $name)
{
    $orderState = new OrderState();
        $orderState->name =  array_fill(0,10,$name);
        $orderState->send_email = false;
        $orderState->color = 'royalblue';
        $orderState->hidden = false;
        $orderState->delivery = false;
        $orderState->logable = false;
        $orderState->invoice = false;

    $order_state.delete();
}
```

However, when I try to uninstall the module I get the following error message

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function delete() in D:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\modules\example\example.php on line 114
[PrestaShop] Fatal error in module example:
Call to undefined function delete()
```

TL,DR; I want to know

- What does the 10 in the array_fill stands for? My best guess is that it is related to the number of installed languages, but couldn't confirm it.
- Is there any way to retrieve the orderState without querying explicitly the database, such as a getOrderState function?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

1º - You have to pass by parameter the `order_state_id`.

2º - To access a method, you have to use like this:

```
$obj->method
```

instead of

```
$obj.method
```

Follow my example:

```
public function deleteOrderState($id_order_state) {

    $orderState = new OrderState($id_order_state);        
    $orderState->delete();

}
```

Then, to delete an `OrderState`, first you need to know its ID.

Later, just do this:

```
$yourObj->deleteOrderState(59);
```